# My Debian Server have a dynamic ip address. Have one program like a VPN to give a Static IP?

Tags: debian, vpn, openvpn, static-ip, dynamic-ip

I need put a website to work, but my desktop doesn't have a static IP, only a dynamic IP. The internet provider created a lot of difficulties to upgrade my internet to statics IPs. I tried to put in he a DDNS, but I wanted a static IP to this machine.

I wanted to know if is possible install in this machine a VPN or something that a dedicated IP and to configure my Website? Have some program or something that do it service?

Put a program or something that give a static IP in my server.

I read in this topic something like I need: [VPN and local Apache port forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/1101955/vpn-and-local-apache-port-forwarding).

I can use OpenVPN to give a static IP to my server? If yes, have some video, article or something to help me to put work?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+dns+services+compared

Comment: DDNS server works good, but I want a static IP to this server, without dynamic solutions.

Comment: Then there is just one way; chat with your ISP.

Comment: Don't have any other option? Because with my ISP is impossible...

Comment: Google Amazon AWS.

Comment: I read this reply : https://qr.ae/pryyFi, can I earn a static ipv6 with this?

About the Google and Amazon AWS, exist one free way ?